# Считывание из текстового файла чисел

Tags: python

Есть текстовый файл, из него надо записать в список числа, заключенные между такими символами ":=" и ";", те, например, есть строка "a:=-1; b:=4", на выходе получаем [-1, 4].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для любого формата файла, вытащит все числа из записей вида
`[:=[ПробельныеСимволы]Число[ПробельныеСимволы];]`

```
import re

#my_file = open(filename)  
#my_str = my_file.read()  
#my_file.close()  
my_str = "a:=1;\na:=1a;\nb:=;\nc:=\n\n22\n\n;"
regexp = re.compile( ":=\s*(-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?)\s*;", re.M )
res = regexp.findall( my_str )
```

Comment: При открытии файла запись должна быть такого типа: `#my_file = open('C:\...\file.txt')`?

Comment: Если работать с файлом, то нужно:<br>
3,4,5 строки РАСкомментировать,<br>
5 строку ЗАкомментировать<br>
заменить `filename` на имя файла.

Comment: Понятно, что раскомментировать=) Видимо, 6 строку закомментить, всё работает как надо. Большое спасибо:)

Comment: в примере в вопросе нет `;` в конце строки, можно `;|$` использовать: `map(int, re.findall(r'(?m):=(.+?)(?:;|$)', "a:=-1; b:=4"))`

Answer (score 1):

```
f=open(filename)  
filetostr=f.read()  
f.close()  
result=[int(k.split(":=")[1].strip()) for k in filetostr.split(";")]
```

Возможно, Вам поможет этот простой пример.

Answer (score 1):

Навскидку, нет интерпретатора под рукой:

```
f = open('/somewhere/file.txt', 'r')  
data = f.read()  
final_list = []  
pre_formatted = data.split(';')
for d in pre_formatted:  
   final_list.append(int(d.split(':=')[1])  
# final_list есть результирующий список
```

Answer (score 0):

Задача на типичный regex `':=([0-9\-\.]);'`